# Как разбить вывод из mysql постраничнно?

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет, при создании сайта я столкнулся с проблемой, как разделить вывод информации с базы данных на несколько страниц. Пробовал предлагаемые скрипты, но они не работали. Жду помощи от профи.

Answer (score 2):

В mysql можно делать ограничение выборки с помощью LIMIT. Например, выбрать 30 записей из таблицы:
'SELECT `field1`, `field2` ... FROM `tablename` LIMIT 0,30;'
Этот запрос выдаст 30 записей. Чтобы получить следующие 30 - нужно написать так 'LIMIT 31,30'. Думаю, схема понятна: нужно задать страницу и количество выводимых элементов. 
Страница * количество выводимых элементов - это 1я цифра в конструкции LIMIT, количество выводимых элементов - вторая.

Comment: Я так понимаю это надо на одной странице указать

'SELECT field1, field2 ... FROM tablename LIMIT 0,30;'

А на второй

'SELECT field1, field2 ... FROM tablename LIMIT 31,60;'

Comment: Перед тем как отвечать и путать человека не поленитесь заглянуть в мануал:
    
    [LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]

@kemerov4anin, в вашем случае первый запрос выдаст с 0 до 30 записи. Во втором случае с 31 до 91.

Comment: @Dex, каюсь, грешен. =)

Answer (score 0):

```
$currentPage = (isset $_GET['p_id'] and !empty($_GET['p_id'])) ? (int) $_GET['p_id'] : 1;
$limit = 30; // 30 объектов на страницу
$offset = $limit * ($currentPage - 1);

$queryCountAll = "select count(1) as countAll from tbl";
$resQueryCountAll = mysql_query($queryCountAll); // запрос на кол-во объектов всего.
...
$countAll = ...; // Кол-во объектов всего.(для формирования пагинации)

$queryObjsForCurrentPage = "select * from tbl limit {$offset},{$limit}";
$resObjsForCurrentPage = mysql_query($queryObjsForCurrentPage);
$ObjsForCurrentPage = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($resObjsForCurrentPage)){
   $ObjsForCurrentPage[] = $row;
}
```

Ну и листалку со ссылками делаешь. Для этого у тебя есть количество объектов всего и колич-во объектов на страницу => узнаешь сколько всего страниц и генеришь ссылки. Как-то так примерно:

```
$pagesCount = ceil($countAll/$limit);
for($i = 1; $i <= $pagesCount; $i++){
  echo '<a href = "index.php?p_id='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';
}
```

Comment: isset $_GET['p_id'] and !empty($_GET['p_id']) о да , эт чтоб наверника ?

Comment: не называйте переменные таким вот **СТРАШНЫМ** образом, умоляю...
`$queryObjsForCurrentPage` - эта же полный \*\*\*\*\*

Это примерно как

     $parsedStringToDataByExplodeFunctionAndThenRedirect

зачем так писать никогда не понимал и, наверное( может и к лучшем ) не пойму...

Comment: Почему у меня на экране выдает вот это '.$i.''; } ?>

Comment: AlexWindHope вполне хорошее название

Comment: Я так не думаю, хорошее название должно быть понятным и, как ни странно - коротким, да и я писал выше уже

зачем так писать никогда не понимал и, наверное( может и к лучшем ) не пойму...

Comment: Alex, тебе за комменты деньги платят? Не лень тебе распинаться по мелочам?=)

Answer (score 0):

Как уже писали выше для этого используется `LIMIT`, мы будем принимать $_GET['page'] и по его значению уже пытаться отдать ту или иную страницу. Более того мы немного усложним пример и добавим подсчет количества страниц

```
// подключение к БД
define("PER_PAGE_LIMIT", 10); // количество материала на 1у страницу
// функция получения значений таблицы по значению страницы
function getByPage($page) {
     $limit = ($page-1)*PER_PAGE_LIMIT . ', ' . PER_PAGE_LIMIT;
     $dbResult = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM someTable LIMIT ' . $limit);
     $result = array();
     while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($dbResult)) {
          $result[] = $row;
     }
     return $result;
}
// функция подсчета общего количества страниц
function countPages() {
     $dbResult = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM someTable'));
     $pagesTotal = floor($dbResult['total'] / PER_PAGE_LIMIT);
     return $pagesTotal;
}
if(!empty($_GET['page'])) {
    if(is_numeric($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] > 0) {
        $page = $_GET['page'];
        $pagesTotal = countPages();
        if($page <= $pagesTotal) {
             $data = getByPage($page);
             // дальше код вывода, будь то подключение шаблона
             // или прямо в коде - не важно
             exit(); //все ок, завершаем работу скрипта...
        }
    }
    // если что-то пошло не так
    // тут мы как-то оповещаем пользователя, либо выводим 404, вообщем тут описываем
    // ошибочную ситуацию
}
```

Вот если нигде не накосячил(т.к. писал с балды как только проснулся :) ) - как-то так...

Comment: В вашем примере у меня на экран выходит вот этот текст

0) {
        $page = $_GET['page'];
        $pagesTotal = countPages();
        if($page <= $pagesTotal) {
             $data = getByPage($page);
             exit(); 
        }
    }
}

Comment: у вас что интерпритатор не установлен?О_о

Это не текст а код и выводится он не должен по определению, возможны ошибки, возможно что не работает, работает не так как надо или что-то в этом духе, но если у вас выводится код значит у вас проблемы с настройками( чего и где не спрашивайте - не имею ни  малейшего представления )

Comment: Кстати скорее всего по этой-же причине у вас не работали и предыдущие примеры ;)